# The problem with android package name unavailability?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have a android app package name. I am using firebase for some services in my app and I was able to get this package name in firebase. The problem is I now want to put my app to google play store but when I try to upload my apk file into google play console it tells me that this package name is already taken. But when search google play store with this package name there is no app shown. So all I think at this point is since I got the package name in firebase, google thinks package name is taken but I am using same account for both firebase and google play console. So do you guys have any idea what can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty likely the package name is taken by an app, possibly one that has been unpublished, or isn't available to you. Possibly the developer only has it available in Alpha or Beta, or a closed testing track. Just pick another package name.

The best design is to pick a package name which starts with a domain name you own, backwards. So if I own nickfortescue.com, choose com.nickfortescue.myapp. This helps reduce the chance of collisions.

As far as I know package name does not affect search indexing in Play, so the package name doesn't matter that much. Just choose a different one and move on.

Comment: make sense but then why I was able to get it on firebase, they are not related? So if I the package name, then I need to change it from firebase too but could not find how to change it.

Comment: Firebase is separate from Play, the same as it is separate from the Apple app store. It trusts you to get your details right, it doesn't reserve them

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's taken but app isn't visible in your country or app isn't compatible with your device.

Comment: I am not lookin from my device or country I am looking trouh this url  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=

Comment: No matter, your package id is taken by app that is visible only in some countries, maybe one, and you can't see it until you enable VPN for that country.